# Automatically acquire IPV6 address in CentOS 6

Tags: centos6, ipv6, linux-networking, ethernet

The network has fixed IPv4 address, and automatic acquired IPv6 address. Does anyone have an idea how to setup? Thanks a lot!

I didn't use NetworkManager. The following is my setting, but it does not work :(

/etc/sysconfig/network:

```
NETWORKING=yes 
HOSTNAME=desk.myname.ca 
NETWORKING_IPV6=yes 
IPV6FORWARDING=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 :

```
DEVICE=eth0 
TYPE="Ethernet" 
UUID=29b0480a-83aa-4124-ab27-01dda940afv3 
ONBOOT=yes 
NM_CONTROLLED=no 
BOOTPROTO=none 
IPADDR=214.52.131.212 
GATEWAY=214.52.137.1 
NETMASK=255.255.255.0 
DNS1=214.52.101.101 
DNS2=214.52.101.100
NAME="System eth0" 
HWADDR=49:73:E6:CC:6A:26
IPV6INIT=yes 
IPV6_AUTOCONFIG=yes
```

I could not get the a global IPV6 address, as shown by the output of ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 49:73:E6:CC:6A:26  
          inet addr:214.52.131.212 Bcast:214.52.137.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4637:e6ff:fecc:6a26/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2721783 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:526400 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:731944071 (698.0 MiB)  TX bytes:107641953 (102.6 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:3020 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3020 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:92956 (90.7 KiB)  TX bytes:92956 (90.7 KiB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 79:73:E1:1C:AA:61  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

Comment: Your configuration is mostly correct. Has IPv6 actually been deployed to your network?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, you're expecting a stateless autoconfig address, correct? From your configuration and the information provided, it appears that there is no router running ipv6 on the network that the interface is connected to, and so it is instead defaulting to link-local. Could you provide some information on network structure? Also, are you certain that if there IS a router running ipv6 that it does not have auto configuration disabled? This would also cause the same symptoms.

Comment: Yes. I expect to have a stateless autoconfig address. Other windows based computers in the network can successfully have a static IPV4 address and automatically acquired IPV6 address just by installing IPv6 protocol. My network administrator does not know how to setup IPv6 for Linux (since I am the only one here using Linux), but told me that just to setup in auto configuration of IPv6, no static IPV6 address. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try turning off IPV6FORWARDING. If forwarding is enabled autoconf is automatically disabled.

Comment: I set IPV6FORWARDING=no . But after I restart the network: /sbin/service network restart  , I got the following message: 
 Global IPv6 forwarding is disabled in configuration, but not currently disabled in kernel . What should I do to turn off the fowarding? Thanks!
Please restart network with '/sbin/service network restart'

Comment: I changed the file /etc/sysctl.conf: net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 2   
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 0 . The message "Global IPv6 forwarding is disabled in configuration, but not currently disabled in kernel" disappeared. But it still does not have global IPV6 address.

Comment: Run the following: `dmesg | grep eth0`

Comment: The result for dmesg | grep eth0 is:     r8169 0000:05:00.0: eth0: RTL8168f/8111f at 0xffffc90001870000, 44:37:e6:cc:6a:26, XID 08000880 IRQ 34
r8169 0000:05:00.0: eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
r8169 0000:05:00.0: eth0: link down
r8169 0000:05:00.0: eth0: link down
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
r8169 0000:05:00.0: eth0: link up
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
.......
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
r8169 0000:05:00.0: eth0: link up
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
eth0: no IPv6 routers present

Comment: @user211258 Windows-based computers are not a good measure as they will always use Teredo to assign themselves an IPv6 address. Are those addresses probably in the 2001:0::/32 range? Then it is Teredo. And your eth0 interface at least says "no IPv6 routers present".

Comment: I checked one windows computer, it indeed use Teredo, its address is 2001:cc0:C002 ... What's the solution for linux then? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to do SLAAC, you have to have a router that's sending Router Advertisements (RA), to provide the network prefix and prefix length.  That will also have the default gateway.

Something, somewhere on the local subnet needs to send the RAs.  Usually its the router, but there are some tools to have a Linux (or BSD) box send the RAs on behalf of the local router, if it' not able (like some home routers).

Also, make sure that you are accepting the RAs. See

net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra

net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra

and make sure they are set to 1